# Can I modify matches in a replacement in Atom/find-and-replace?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Given the following buffer:

```
#  event      :string(255)
#  message    :text
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  read       :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  level      :integer
```

I would like to replace this with [YARD formatted](https://github.com/lsegal/yard) comments:

```
# @attr event [String] (255)
# @attr message [Text] 
# @attr user_id [Integer] 
# @attr created_at [Datetime] 
# @attr updated_at [Datetime] 
# @attr read [Boolean] default(FALSE)
# @attr level [Integer]
```

My search expression is:

```
^#\s\s(\w*)\s*:(\w*)\s*([\w|\(|\)]*)\s*$
```

And the replacement:

```
# @attr $1 [$2] $3
```

This gives me very close to what I want except that the "type" is lowercased.

```
# @attr event [string] (255)
# @attr message [text] 
# @attr user_id [integer] 
# @attr created_at [datetime] 
# @attr updated_at [datetime] 
# @attr read [boolean] default(FALSE)
# @attr level [integer]
```

Is it possible to modify the `$2` replacement to get it with the first letter in uppercase?